# WPF get controls collided with line

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a led panel which looks like [this](http://s14.directupload.net/images/120510/qg3qqdar.jpg). This is built with a canvas object that contains a grid with columns and rows. Each field of that matrix contains a LED control which contains an ellipse.

Now I want to draw a line on the canvas. I think I am able to do that but how can I get all LED controls which are on that line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that you draw a [System.Windows.Shapes.Line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.line), you could get the [Geometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometry) of the Line by the [RenderedGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.shape.renderedgeometry) property and use that Geometry as input for a geometry [hit-test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752097.aspx).

Such a hit-test would be done by a call to [VisualTreeHelper.HitTest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608753.aspx) with a [GeometryHitTestParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.geometryhittestparameters.aspx) argument. HitTest would call your [HitTestResultCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.hittestresultcallback.aspx) for every ellipse that is covered by the line's geometry.

I am not completely sure whether geometry hit-testing would work with "empty" geometries like a line with zero width. But you could give it a try and in case it doesn't work use for example a tilted rectangle geometry instead of the line. Or you could simulate the use of a Pen with a certain thickness by creating a "widened" geometry with [Geometry.GetWidenedPathGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms615692).

Comment: perfect thank you soo much. Until now i have always used winforms. I just wanted to start calculating the line and compare x and y and so on ^^

Comment: ok i ve got a new problem now. With line it works fine. But now i tried it with a Rectangle.
There I have the problem that I set the positions with Canvas.SetLeft/Top and Width/Height.
If i call HitTest now in the RenderedGeometry the left and top bounds are 1.0. So how can i solve this problem?

Comment: You could simply create a [RectangleGeometry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry.aspx) from an appropriate [Rect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.rectanglegeometry.rect.aspx).

Comment: ok i ll try it... wpf framework is just 2 big... :( i really should read a book...